# Error (One of parameters is not of the type Integer) while clicking the 'mailing.viewUrl' in a sent mailing

Tags: civimail

In sent Mailings, the 'mailing.viewUrl' is rendered into:
https://terranova.tamera.org/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=95c21fb7cc1b7aac

and clicking it gives me this error:

> $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => One of parameters (value: e05fa931f15dedbb) is not of the type Integer [code] => )

With the following stack trace:

> $backTrace = #0 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(343): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(535): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters (value: e05fa931f15dedbb) is not of the type Integer") #2 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1519): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("e05fa931f15dedbb", "Integer") #3 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1397): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("\nSELECT CF.id as cfID,\n CF.uri as uri,\n CF.mime_typ...", (Array:2), TRUE) #4 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/File.php(332): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nSELECT CF.id as cfID,\n CF.uri as uri,\n CF.mime_typ...", (Array:2)) #5 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Mailing.php(571): CRM_Core_BAO_File::getEntityFile("civicrm_mailing", "e05fa931f15dedbb") #6 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(101): civicrm_api3_mailing_preview((Array:3)) #7 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(168): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9)) #8 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(99): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9)) #9 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(43): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Mailing", "preview", (Array:3)) #10 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/View.php(145): civicrm_api3("Mailing", "preview", (Array:3)) #11 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Mailing_Page_View->run((Array:3), NULL) #12 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15)) #13 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3)) #14 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3)) #15 /home/tamera/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("mailing", "view") #16 /home/tamera/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #17 {main}

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm running Civi 5.14.1 on Drupal

Comment: Under `Administer > CiviMail Component Settings`, is `Hashed Mailing URL's` ticked?

Comment: Yes, Hashed Mailing URL's is ticked.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1037

You could try applying [the PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14508) linked there - or wait since it has been merged so will be in a release soon.